# How to do numpy logical_and with a margin?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vector, data-science

I have two numpy vector arrays, one contains binary values so either 1 or 0 and the other float values so anything in between 0 and 1.

I want to use the `numpy.logical_and` operator and have it return true if the binary value is in the range of the float plus or minus 0.2. So i.e. a float of 0.1 would return true, 0.4 false.

How would I tackle this?

Comment: Are you planning to use the `ufunc` functionality of `logical_and` (i.e. `logical_and.accumulate()`,  `.reduce()`, `.at()` . . . )?  Or just the basic function?

Comment: I did not plan to do it, is it needed?

Comment: Probably not, but I wanted to make sure, as the built-in `numpy` function (`np.isclose`) is not a `ufunc` and can't do the extra things `logical_and` can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `np.isclose`.  In this case implementation would be:

```
bin_arr = np.random.randint(2, size = 100)
float_arr = np.random.rand(100)
out = np.isclose(bin_arr.astype(float), float_arr, atol = .2)
```

Note that while `logical_and` is a [`ufunc` (Universal Function)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) with extended functionality,  `np.isclose` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Does the question require `True if (float_arr less than 0.2) AND (bin_arr > 0)`.  Which does need the use of logical and.

Or  `True if abs(float_arr - bin_arr) <= 0.2` which doesn't.  `@Daniel F` 's use of isclose() is an elegant answer to this.

```
# Set up some data
np.random.seed(0)  # Make it repeatable.
bin_arr = np.random.randint(2, size = 20)
float_arr = np.random.rand(20) 
bin_arr, float_arr

# (array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
# array([0.79172504, 0.52889492, 0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606,
#        0.0871293 , 0.0202184 , 0.83261985, 0.77815675, 0.87001215,
#        0.97861834, 0.79915856, 0.46147936, 0.78052918, 0.11827443,
#        0.63992102, 0.14335329, 0.94466892, 0.52184832, 0.41466194]))
```

True if (float_arr less than 0.2) AND (bin_arr > 0)`.

```
np.logical_and( float_arr<=0.2, bin_arr)
# array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
#        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
#        False, False])
```

True if abs(float_arr - bin_arr) <= 0.2

```
np.abs(float_arr - bin_arr)<=0.2
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
#        True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
#        False, False])
```